# How to pass custom version to sbt release?

Tags: scala, sbt, release

I need to pass a custom version to the SBT release task. I'm currently running this:

```
sbt "release with-defaults release-version 1.2.3 next-version 1.3.0"
```

But I get this:

```
[info] Loading project definition from F:\dev\MyProject\project
[info] Set current project to ipo-renew (in build file:/F:/dev/MyProject/)
[error] Expected whitespace character
[error] Expected 'with-defaults'
[error] Expected 'skip-tests'
[error] Expected 'cross'
[error] release with-defaults release-version 20.0.5-XML-Hotfix-1 next-version 20.0.5-XML-Hotfix-2
[error]                       ^
```

I've tried without the quotes:

```
sbt release with-defaults release-version 1.2.3 next-version 1.3.0
```

But I then get prompted for a version, rather than it using the ones I've supplied.

As far as I can tell from the sbt release plugin docs (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release) I'm passing the right stuff in - any ideas why it's ignored? I eventually need this to work from a command line step in TeamCity...

I've also tried omitting the 'with-defaults' option but it makes no difference to the result. However running just

```
sbt release with-defaults
```

correctly doesn't prompt me and uses the version we have in version.sbt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you're using [the latest `sbt-release` version](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release#usage) (currently 1.0.3 as of 18/10/2016):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.3")
```

Run `with-defaults` as the last argument of the command:

```
sbt "release release-version 1.2.3 next-version 1.3.0 with-defaults"
```

Here's the output from  running inside TeamCity:

```
[19:46:27]  [Step 2/2] [info] Checking remote [origin] ...
[19:46:32]  [Step 2/2] [info] Setting version to '1.2.3'.
[19:46:32]  [Step 2/2] [info] Reapplying settings...
[19:46:34]  [Step 2/2] [info] Set current project to ***
[19:46:34]  [Step 2/2] [info] [development 7302685] Setting version to 1.2.3
[19:46:34]  [Step 2/2] [info]  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[19:46:34]  [Step 2/2] [info] Reapplying settings...
[19:46:35]  [Step 2/2] [info] Set current project to ***
[19:46:35]  [Step 2/2] [info] git push sends its console output to standard error, which will cause the next few lines to be marked as [error].
[19:46:36]  [Step 2/2] [error] To ****
[19:46:36]  [Step 2/2] [error]    4342272..7302685  development -> development
[19:46:37]  [Step 2/2] [error] Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Was in the middle of editing as you replied... I've already tried this and still get prompted for a version

Comment: `with-defaults` used the configuration you provide via `build.sbt`. I'll run a few tests with this.

Comment: @ssloan Try running "with-defaults" at the end of the command (see my update).

Comment: Still not working for me. This is what I run in TeamCity: `sbt "release release-version %release-version% next-version %next-version% with-defaults"` and I get the same error as before: `
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error] Expected whitespace character
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error] Expected 'with-defaults'
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error] Expected 'skip-tests'
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error] Expected 'cross'
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error] release release-version 20.0.5-XML-Hotfix-1 next-version 20.0.5-XML-Hotfix-2 with-defaults
[08:59:01][Step 3/3] [error]         ^`

Comment: @ssloan Which sbt version are you using?

Comment: SBT version is 0.13.8

Comment: @ssloan Anything changes when you upgrade to 0.13.11?

Comment: That's really weird. Which version of sbt release are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125985/discussion-between-ssloan-and-yuval-itzchakov).